# 0x80070005 - Access is denied. for a Dom node returned from a function

Tags: com, autohotkey

Can't we use a COM object created in a function outside the function?

```
strHTML := "<html><body>foobar</body></html>"
oNode := GetNode(strHTML, "body", 0)
msgbox % oNode.innerText

GetNode(strHTML, strNode, nIndex) {
    doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
    doc.write(strHTML)
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(strNode)[nIndex]
}
```

> Error:  0x80070005 - Access is denied.
>
> Specifically: innerText
>
> Line#   001: strHTML := "foobar"  002: oNode
>   := GetNode(strHTML, "body", 0)
>   --->  003: MsgBox,oNode.innerText     005: {  006: doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")    007: doc.write(strHTML)     008:
>   Return,doc.getElementsByTagName(strNode)[nIndex]  009: }  010: Exit
>     011: Exit

Neither a global variable nor a byref parameter did help.

---

@SouthStExit This doesn't work so it becomes pointless to wrap it in a function. But as Lexikos mentioned, I see now the object gets destroyed so it becomes not accessible.

```
oNode1 := GetNode("<html><body>foo</body></html>", "body", 0)
oNode2 := GetNode("<html><body><div>bar</div></body></html>", "div", 0)

msgbox % oNode1.innerText "`n" oNode2.innerText

GetNode(strHTML, strNode, nIndex) {
    global doc
    doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
    doc.write(strHTML)
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(strNode)[nIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make *doc* global.

```
strHTML :=  "<html><body>foobar</body></html>"
oNode :=    GetNode(strHTML, "body", 0)
msgbox %    oNode.innerText
return

GetNode(strHTML, strNode, nIndex) {
    global  doc
    doc :=  ComObjCreate("HTMLfile"), doc.write(strHTML)
    return  doc.getElementsByTagName(strNode)[nIndex]
}
```

Comment: This is presumably because the document is destroyed when the reference contained within the local variable is released. If you write equivalent code without a function (i.e. doc := "" before accessing oNode), you will get the same result.

Comment: Thanks Lexikos. I got it now. So it's not practical to use nodes outside functions.